# Why return 0 statement doesn't pass the value zero?

Tags: c++, function, return-value

I have just started learning C++ and after getting accustomed to data types, I am learning about functions and variables in programs. However, I couldn't really follow what action is the return statement intended for.

My college course's slides say return statement returns control back to the OS if the caller is not a function. But I don't understand what does returning program control back to the caller precisely mean. Does it mean that the controller in the CPU directs to execute the following instruction? They also say it passes the value 0. What does this mean? I don't see any such return value when I tried executing a program.

Please explain what does it mean to return program control to the caller and also why is the return value not passed when the return statement is executed?

Comment: this is not your question right place to ask. if you have a problem with program post it. but its not a class discussion

Comment: Not sure why you got a downvote there. It's a pretty legitimate question.

Comment: You run your program in a terminal and the terminal can see that return value. Bash uses non-zero values to mean an error occured and it acts appropriately in response.

Returning control means that Bash gets to control what operations happen on the CPU not your program anymore.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, no it is not. For every C++ primer there is returning from main is most likely described in the second sentence of the book.

Comment: Fair enough. Voting to closebased on that reasoning.

Comment: OP, check the examples on this page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return. While the stuff at the top may seem kinda technical, the examples are very straightforward and should help you understand.

Comment: @SiddharthJoshi. You can ask for more on Google. Just type something like "C++ tutorial return statement".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statements in a function are executed one by one in precisely the order they are stated. When a statement is a function call the control is given to the called function and the statement in this function are processed until the end of the function and then control goes back to the original function, i.e. the caller.

A return statement can be used to immediately jump back to the caller without processing any further statements in a function. Depending on whether the function is supposed to return a value you can (and have to) specify a return value.

The sequence of jumps from one function to the other and from a statement to the next is referred to as the control flow. The machine can only process at most one statement at a time and the function with the current statement is said to have control. Of course this is simplfied but I think this simplification is appropriate with regard to your question.

Comment: What does control precisely mean?

Comment: @SiddharthJoshi It is not easy to explain a concept like that on a website like this. (Hopefully) they will cover it later in the course you're taking.

Comment: So aren't my slides wrong in saying that it passes the value zero?

Comment: If the statement "return 0" is executed the value 0 is in fact passed to the caller. The caller can use it like this: "int value = FunctionReturningZero();" After executing this statement the variable "value" will have value 0,

Comment: Is that a null value?

Comment: Well, in this form it is just an integer that has the value 0. Like a function calculating the sum of two numbers returns a value, any function can return an integer value.

Answer (score 2):

The return value from `main` isn't really a return value. It's called an ["exit status"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status), and it goes to the program that ran your program. The purpose of this is, if someone is using your program along with several others, you can tell them that something went wrong and they should stop what they're doing.

Regarding the return value from normal functions, they will probably cover that later in the course you're taking. Unfortunately a good explanation of these is beyond the scope of this answer.